# Julian to gregorian date with OutOfBoundsDatetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm working with a pandas dataframe and I have a DATE column that contains a julian date. I want to convert every value of that column to a gregorian date.

To achieve that I used the following code:

```
df[['DATE']] = df[['DATE']].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x - pd.Timestamp(0).to_julian_date(), unit='D'))
```

Unfortunately, I get an error that looks like this:

```
OutOfBoundsDatetime: ("cannot convert input 381088.5 with the unit 'D'", u'occurred at index MXPLD_DATE')
```

When I look for the input value that causing problem in the dataframe, it doesn't exist at all, I don't know where `381088.5` come from.

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

#### EDIT 1

I tried @jezrael solution but I still got a similar error.

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], unit='D', origin='julian')
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OutOfBoundsDatetime                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-4353e2be1ced> in <module>()
----> 1 df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], unit='D', origin='julian')

/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.pyc in to_datetime(arg, errors, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, box, format, exact, unit, infer_datetime_format, origin)
    469             raise tslib.OutOfBoundsDatetime(
    470                 "{original} is Out of Bounds for "
--> 471                 "origin='julian'".format(original=original))
    472 
    473     elif origin not in ['unix', 'julian']:

OutOfBoundsDatetime: 0          2457184
1          2457155
2          2457155
3          2457155
4          2457155
5          2457155
6          2457155
7          2457155
8          2457155
9          2457155
10         2457155
11         2457155
12         2457155
13         2457155
14         2457155
15         2457155
16         2457155
17         2457155
18         2457155
19         2457155
20         2457155
21         2457155
22         2457155
23         2457155
24         2457155
25         2457155
26         2457155
27         2457155
28         2457701
29         2457701
            ...   
4597928    2457724
4597929    2457724
4597930    2457724
4597931    2457724
4597932    2457724
4597933    2457724
4597934    2457724
4597935    2457724
4597936    2457724
4597937    2457724
4597938    2457724
4597939    2457724
4597940    2457724
4597941    2457724
4597942    2457724
4597943    2457724
4597944    2457724
4597945    2457724
4597946    2457724
4597947    2457724
4597948    2457724
4597949    2457724
4597950    2457724
4597951    2457724
4597952    2457724
4597953    2457724
4597954    2457724
4597955    2457724
4597956    2457724
4597957    2457724
Name: DATE, Length: 4597958, dtype: int64 is Out of Bounds for origin='julian'
```

Comment: Look at the output of `pd.Timestamp(0).to_julian_date()`: `2440587.5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with parameter `origin`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'julian':[2458072.5, 2458073.5]})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['julian'], unit='D', origin='julian')
print (df)
      julian       date
0  2458072.5 2017-11-15
1  2458073.5 2017-11-16
```

EDIT:

There is problem some datetime `OutOfBounds`.

So first checked [timestamp limitations](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations):

```
In [66]: pd.Timestamp.min
Out[66]: Timestamp('1677-09-21 00:12:43.145225')

In [67]: pd.Timestamp.max
Out[67]: Timestamp('2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807')
```

And then get minimal julian datetimes (by convertin online, e.g. [here](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/jdconverter?ID=AA&year=1677&month=9&day=21&era=1&hr=0&min=0&sec=0.0)):

```
maxdate = 2547338
mindate = 2333836
```

Then add `NaN` for dates out of range, e.g. by [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'julian':[2821676, 2547338, 1, 2333836]})
maxdate = 2547338
mindate = 2333836

clean_dates = df['julian'].where(df['julian'].between(mindate, maxdate))
print (clean_dates)
0          NaN
1    2547338.0
2          NaN
3    2333836.0

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(clean_dates, unit='D', origin='julian')
print (df)
    julian                date
0  2821676                 NaT
1  2547338 2262-04-10 12:00:00
2        1                 NaT
3  2333836 1677-09-21 12:00:00
```

And last apply solution to your data - there are 2 values converted to `NaT`:

```
print (df['MXPLD_DATE'][~df['MXPLD_DATE'].between(mindate, maxdate)])

1217806    2821676
3167148    2821676
Name: MXPLD_DATE, dtype: int64

clean_dates = df['MXPLD_DATE'].where(df['MXPLD_DATE'].between(mindate, maxdate))        
df['MXPLD_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(clean_dates, unit='D', origin='julian')
print (df['MXPLD_DATE'])
0         2015-06-10 12:00:00
1         2015-05-12 12:00:00
2         2015-05-12 12:00:00
3         2015-05-12 12:00:00
4         2015-05-12 12:00:00
5         2015-05-12 12:00:00
6         2015-05-12 12:00:00
7         2015-05-12 12:00:00
8         2015-05-12 12:00:00
9         2015-05-12 12:00:00
10        2015-05-12 12:00:00
```

Comment: I tried your approach but I still get the same error. I copied the stacktrace in my post.

Comment: Hmmm, are your data `julian dates` ? Can you add data sample?

Comment: Yes, I think so. When I apply your command on a random value it works like a charm. pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'][0], unit='D', origin='julian') it works.

Comment: I think there are some bad data, so need `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['julian'], unit='D', origin='julian', errors='coerce')` for convert them to NaT.

Comment: I added the error parameter and still the same error than the one that I pasted in the original post.

Comment: I have an idea - is possible use `df['DATE'].to_pickle('data.pkl')` and share it? Because it seems some data related issue.

Comment: here it is https://wetransfer.com/downloads/4e3546aac95224ade629e6705b93bac020171115141202/7f74ff

Comment: I get it, there are 2 bad values `OutOfBoundsDatetime: 
2821676
2821676`

Comment: I try it convert to dates - http://aa.usno.navy.mil/jdconverter?ID=AA&jd=2821676 and this date is too big for pandas - check [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations)

Comment: Thank you so much for the investigation. Do you think it's possible to put a condition that verifies that i'm inside the bounds that the pandas doc specifies while i'm doing the conversion using datetime ?

Comment: Yes, I add it to answer ;)